# Cursor? Loop? Aggregate up rows data along with row results

Tags: sql, loops, cursor, sybase

I have the following table & data

Table name = MyTable

```
Description | Partition     | Total
------------|---------------|--------------
CASH        | Reconciled    | 25
CASH        | Adjustm       | 50
CASH        | Balanc        | 120
LOANS       | Adjustm       | 44
LOANS       | Balanc        | 32
CARDS       | Adjustm       | 81
CARDS       | Balanc        | 67
MTG         | Adjustm       | 14
MTG         | Balanc        | 92
```

The requirement is simple enough - it's a straight select from the table, but for each unique description, I need to sum up the totals of all the partitions, such that the user will see

```
Description | Partition     | Total
------------|---------------|--------------
CASH        | TOTAL         | 195   <
CASH        | Reconciled    | 25
CASH        | Adjustm       | 50
CASH        | Balanc        | 120
LOANS       | TOTAL         | 76    <
LOANS       | Adjustm       | 44
LOANS       | Balanc        | 32
CARDS       | TOTAL         | 148   <
CARDS       | Adjustm       | 81
CARDS       | Balanc        | 67
MTG         | TOTAL         | 106   <
MTG         | Adjustm       | 14
MTG         | Balanc        | 92
```

It's a stored proc I'm writing - I don't have the option of pulling this into a MT to perform this so I need to perform it in the body of the stored proc.  Am I looking at some while Loop or Cursor to provide the roll up I need, or is there another glaringly obvious and easy solution that I'm just not seeing?  Aside from the roll up, it's a straight

```
select * from MyTable
```

DB is Sybase.

Thanks

Comment: Check out Rollup. http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00800.1510/html/iqapgv2/CIHDFIFE.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the [GROUPING SETS](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/ug-olap-s-51258141.html) extension of the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT  Description, 
        COALESCE(Parition, 'Total') AS Partition,
        SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Description, Partition), (Description));
```

or you could use:

```
SELECT  Description, 
        COALESCE(Parition, 'Total') AS Partition,
        SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Description, Partition);
```

Without ROLLUP, you can do this using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT  Description, 
        Parition,
        Total
FROM    MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  Description, 
        'Total' AS Partition,
        SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY Description;
```

Comment: I think GROUP BY ROLLUP (Description, Partition) is more suitable no !?!

Comment: Possibly, I originally went for grouping sets because I am used to SQL Server where using rollup on two columns gives rolls up all combinations, so wouldn't have given the desired results. However, sybase doesn't do this so I'd expect both options would give the exact same results and query plan. I've added the query with ROLLUP too.

Comment: Many thanks (& @Jazz), however it seems that my Sybase version (ASE 15.7) doesn't support ROLLUP, which is ticking me off as it looks exactly like what I want!